# How to use abstract class from Thymeleaf template to Spring boot controller?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have this structure model for my application :

```java
public class Garage
List<Vehicule> vehicules;

...

public abstract class Vehicule
List<Wheel> wheels

...

public class Car extends Vehicule
public class Bike extends Vehicule

... 

public class Wheel
boolean damaged
```

And I have a form which contains a checkbox input to let him know if a wheel is damaged :

```html
<form id="garage"
      action="#"
      th:action="@{/save}"
      th:object="${garage}"
      method="post">
            <div th:each="vehicule, i : ${garage.getVehicules()}">
               <ul>
                  <li th:each="wheel, j : ${garage.getWheels()}">
                     <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{{vehicules[__${i.index}__].wheels}}" th:value="${wheel}" />
                    <label th:for="${#ids.next('wheels')}" th:text="${wheel.value}">Label</label>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
```

What I get is this error because of abstract keyword on my vehicule class :

> java.lang.InstantiationException: null
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:502) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:486) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:197)

Last thing, this is not my real code but it's to provide you the most similar context for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as Alfred said I use DTO now.

But I found the solution for my original question with a Converter configuration class and a hidden input in the template :

```html
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{vehicules[__${i.index}__]}" />
```

```java
public class VehiculeConverter implements Converter<String, Vehicule> {
    @Override
    public Vehicule convert(String source) {
        // return Car or Bike
    }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
public class FormattersConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new VehiculeConverter());
    }
}
```

What I understand is in the template the hidden field calls the converter because the controller needs to create Vehicule object from a String.
It works even with abstract keyword.

Answer (score 0):

It means obviously, you handled abstraction inappropriately. You can always use/create Data Transfer Objects as the middleman to handle your data to and from thymeleaf forms.

Comment: What the DTO looks like in this case ? I need polymorphism in the form and not mapping directly fields to neither Car nor Bike.

Comment: Your DTO are just copies of your main entities only in Strings, Integers, or plain Objects of data types because those are the only types that handle data from forms, not specific abstraction of a type. Do the conversion from there with your abstract classes without touching your original entities, and you can add convenience methods too. We can not give you how it will look like because you did not provide enough information about your model structure and how your controller handles the incoming parameters. You can use the DTO to handle incoming parameters and pass model to your views.

Comment: You can have multiple entities data in a single DTO and any other relevant information you would like to pass to your view. One DTO per view.